# Using deferred in multiple $.each loops in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have three each loops and  all three may or may not be dependent on each other depending upon page level filters selected .There are total 3 filters

```
if(filter1 is selected) {
  //runs first $.each loop and alters some of custom attr to DOM element  
}

if(filter2 is selected) {
  // Checks if filter1 was selected and are there any attr changes done by it   
  // runs second $.each loop and alters some of custom attr to DOM element   
}

filter3 .... So on
```

Problem is I need to know if first loop in filter1 has completed its task , then only run second filter loop so that I may get all `attr` changes done by filter1 perfectly.So I am trying to user Deferred object .Below is my code.

```
var defer = $.Deferred();
if(filter1) {
  $.each()
    .promise
    .done(function(){
      defer.resolve();
      return defer.promise()
    });
}

// same goes for filter2 and filter3
```

Now I want if filter1 is selected [*execute loop and return promise*] or 
not selected [*return promise*] and then go into second filter following same process.How can I achieve it , also how would I know that all 3 loops have completed its execution .
Note : There are no ajax call in above process at all.

Comment: The nature of the "filter1" operations is ambiguous. Overall, the question implies asynchronous, but the description "alters some of custom attr to DOM element " implies synchronous.

Comment: @Roamer Yes you are right

Comment: Then let's assume they are asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.when` for aggregation and `then` chaining.

```
function handleFirstFilter(){
    if(firstFilterSelected){
        var ps = [];
        $.each(elements, function(el){
            ps.push(el.animate(...).promise()); // add all the promises
        });
        return $.when.apply($, ps); // aggregate over them
    }
    return $.Deferred().resolve(); // return an empty promise resolved, nothing to do
}
// the other two filters are similar in pattern, can extract it to a function

// now execute them all with each stage waiting for the previous.
handleFirstFilter().then(handleSecondFilter).then(handleThirdFilter)
```

Comment: How would I know that all then statements have completed execution

Answer (score 2):

If your stages depend only on completion of (not data from) the previous stage, and the three filter-handlers differ only in :

- a particular boolean state,
- the elements acted on,
- the asycn function to be applied to each element,

then you could write a generalized `handleFilter()` function as simple as :

```
function handleFilter(selected, asyncFn) {
    // return an aggregated promise or null.
    return selected ? $.when.apply(null, $.map(this, asyncFn)) : null;
}
```

*As written, `handleFilter()` must be called with `.bind()`, `.apply()` or `.call()` in order to establish the value of `this`.*

You would then use `handleFilter.bind()` to make three executables, one for each filter, and pass them to a chain of .then()s for serial execution.

```
$.when()
    .then(handleFilter.bind(elements_1, firstFilterSelected, asyncFn_1))
    .then(handleFilter.bind(elements_2, secondFilterSelected, asyncFn_2))
    .then(handleFilter.bind(elements_3, thirdFilterSelected, asyncFn_3))
    .then(function() {
        //everything complete
    });
```

Each stage will wait for the previous one to complete.

Comment: Thanks I used your Idea but modifed a bit say callfunction1().then(function(){callfunction2().then(function(){callfunction3().then(function(){console.log("I am Done")})})});
But in above code how would I handle , say if callfunction2() is failed or in other words how can know that a particular function is failed

Comment: "... a bit ... "! Has any of my idea survived? I omitted failure handling as it wasn't in the question. How you handle errors depends on the desired behaviour. There are two basic options - stop-on-failure or continue-on-failure.

Answer (score 0):

> "alters some of custom attr to DOM element"

is not an asynchronous action (like a timeout, ajax request, or user interaction). It will have been executed, and finished executing, when the loop is over. All the new attribute values can be observed from the second loop.

**You do not need promises** here, just put your synchronous statements in the right order and they will be evaluated sequentially.